# Show Dyanmic Multiple Lines on Chart in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on app in which I have to show the json data on charts which is a swift framework I am using. I am able to show the data correctly on the charts but can't able to make the function dynamic. So that any n numbers of charts I can show on the LineChart graph.This is the library I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts
.
This is the function I am using to show the datas on graph

```
func newLineChartValue(carbonLineChartValue: [LineChartValue]) {
    
    for value in self.carbonLineChartValue {
        self.zoneNames.append(value.Zone_name!)
        self.allValueArray.append(value.value_array!)
        self.colors.append(value.zone_color!)
    }
    
    var lineChartEntry1 = [ChartDataEntry]()
    var lineChartEntry2 = [ChartDataEntry]()
    var lineChartEntry3 = [ChartDataEntry]()

            
    let firstLineArray = allValueArray[0]
    print("FirstLine Data: \(firstLineArray)")
    var timeLbl = [String]()
    
    var valueOne = [Double]()
    
    for lbl in firstLineArray {
        timeLbl.append(lbl.label!)
        valueOne.append(lbl.value!)
        print("Time1:-> \(timeLbl)")
        print("Value1:-> \(valueOne)")
    }

    for i in 0..<timeLbl.count {
        lineChartEntry1.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(valueOne[i])))
    }
    
    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry1, label: "")
    set1.axisDependency = .left
    set1.mode = .cubicBezier
    set1.setColor(UIColor.init(hex: colors[0]))
    set1.fillColor = UIColor.init(hex: colors[0])
    set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.init(hex: colors[0]))

    set1.lineWidth = 4
    set1.circleRadius = 4
    set1.fillAlpha = 65/255
    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
    
    
    let secondLineArray = allValueArray[1]
    var valueTwo = [Double]()
    for value in secondLineArray {
        valueTwo.append(value.value!)
        print("Value2:-> \(valueTwo)")
    }
    for i in 0..<valueTwo.count {
        lineChartEntry2.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(valueTwo[i])))
    }
    let set2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry2, label: "")
    set2.mode = .cubicBezier

    set2.axisDependency = .left
    set2.setColor(UIColor.init(hex: colors[1]))
    set2.fillColor = UIColor.init(hex: colors[1])
    set2.setCircleColor(UIColor.init(hex: colors[1]))
    set2.lineWidth = 4
    set2.circleRadius = 4
    set2.fillAlpha = 65/255
    set2.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false

    let thirdLine = allValueArray[2]
    var valueThree = [Double]()

    for value in thirdLine {
        valueThree.append(value.value!)
        print("Value3:-> \(valueThree)")
    }
    for i in 0..<valueThree.count {
        lineChartEntry3.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(valueThree[i])))
    }
    let line3 = LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry3, label: "")
    line3.axisDependency = .left
    line3.mode = .cubicBezier
    line3.setColor(UIColor.init(hex: colors[2]))
    line3.fillColor = UIColor.init(hex: colors[2])
    line3.setCircleColor(UIColor.init(hex: colors[2]))

    line3.lineWidth = 4
    line3.circleRadius = 4
    line3.fillAlpha = 65/255
    line3.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false


    
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [set1,set2,line3])
    lineChartData.setDrawValues(false)
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    self.lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(index, _) in
        return timeLbl[Int(index)]
    })
    self.lineChartView.data = lineChartData
    
}
```

This is the Struct for **LineChartValue**

```
struct LineChartValue: Codable {
var Zone_name: String?
var zone_color: String?
var value_array: [LineChartValueArray]?
}
```

JSON Coming from Server

```
{        
            "show_Zone": true
            "Zone_name": "Zone Sales",
            "zone_color": "#c69f49",
            "value_array": [
                {
                    "label": "01:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "02:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "03:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "04:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "05:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "06:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "07:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "08:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "09:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "10:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "11:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "12:00 AM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "01:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "02:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "03:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "04:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "05:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "06:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "07:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "08:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "09:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "10:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "11:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "label": "12:00 PM",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        },
```

I want to make this function dynamic so **I can show n numbers of lines on graph**.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to show a line for each element in `allValueArray` instead of hardcoding 3 lines for the first 3 elements in `allValueArray`?

Comment: Yes if there are 11 lines it will show 11 lines with having zonecolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code reduced to use a loop over `carbonLineChartValue` instead of hardcoding accessing the first 3 elements of the array.

The first iteration of the array populates the `timeLbl` array to replicate you populating that array from the first element.

I've also removed all uses of `!` to avoid possible crashes from force-unwrapping nil values.

Since I do not have your charts library nor several other structures referenced in your code I am not able to verify that this code will compile as written. There may be a mistake or two here from trying to translate your original code. But the general idea should be valid.

I also don't show the initial `for` loop where you populate `self.zoneNames`, `self.allValueArray`, and `self.colors` since it's not needed for this function. Put it back in if you need those results for other uses.

```
func newLineChartValue(carbonLineChartValue: [LineChartValue]) {
    var dataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
    var timeLbl = [String]()

    for (index, chartValue) in carbonLineChartValue.enumerated() {
        guard let zoneName = chartValue.Zone_name, let zoneColor = chartValue.zone_color, let lineArray = chartValue.value_array else { continue }

        // Skip this one if it's not to be shown
        if chartValue.show_Zone == false { continue }

        let lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
        if index == 0 {
            timeLbl = lineArray.compactMap { $0.label }
        }

        for (index, value) in lineArray.enumerated() {
            if let y = value.value {
                lineChartEntry.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: y))
            }
        }

        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry, label: "")
        set.mode = .cubicBezier

        set.axisDependency = .left
        set.setColor(UIColor(hex: zoneColor))
        set.fillColor = UIColor(hex: zoneColor)
        set.setCircleColor(UIColor(hex: zoneColor))
        set.lineWidth = 4
        set.circleRadius = 4
        set.fillAlpha = 65/255
        set.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false

        dataSets.append(set)
    }

    let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    lineChartData.setDrawValues(false)
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    self.lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(index, _) in
        return timeLbl[Int(index)]
    })
    self.lineChartView.data = lineChartData
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250546/discussion-between-wings-and-hangarrash).