# Problem with labels using library Charts with UIKit in XCode 12

Tags: swift, charts, uikit

Hell my friends.I'm developing an app which has to show several charts using UIKit and the library Charts. I've been requested to use both things.

I have two arrays with correct data Ciudades y Precios.
Ciudades is String type and Precios Double type. I'v been reading how to use Charts library for hours but it seems that I dont understand how to use it because the chart I get it's not the one I excpected to. I need a chart with the cities on x label but they are not showed as you can see in the picture.
[image]

This is my code

```
class BarChartViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!
    var nombres: [String]!
    var precios: [Double]!
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barChartView.delegate = self
        nombres = eventos.devolverNombre()
        print(nombres)
        precios = eventos.devolverPrecios()
        setChart(dataPoints: nombres, values: precios)
    }
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        barChartView.noDataText = "Es necesario añadir datos."
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let  dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            if dataEntry != nil {
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)}
        }
        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "PRECIOS POR EVENTO")
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
        chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 126/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)]
        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        barChartView.data = chartData
        barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(index, _) in
                return self.nombres[Int(index)] })
        let labelCount = nombres.count
        print(labelCount)
        barChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(labelCount, force: true)
        barChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 90
        barChartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
        barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824534/show-dyanmic-multiple-lines-on-chart-in-swift/74857648#74857648 check this answer it will solve your problem

Comment: @Wings Thanks! It worked but the problem It's that the labels are showed only in odd positions. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 but not in even position 1,3,5,7 any fix?

Comment: just click on the graph it will show its because of screen size of phone

Comment: No it's not a question of clicking. I've updated my code to show all the labes but there are not center and the last one is not show....Help!!